# Is there any way to create a custom toast notification?

Tags: android, notifications, toast

I want to create a Toast message with custom background and custom rounded border. But it seems I am not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two I think useful examples...
Yesterday I just was looking for it, because I'm also interessted in it.

http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/161

[helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-customize-toasts](http://helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-customize-toasts)

Not able to post more than one link -.-
That's why the second one is as text...

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

This link is a starting point - not sure about which elements of the toast can be customised:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

This link (with the example XML) shows how you can change the toast background and other attributes

whereas this link shows the margin customisation possibilities (in code):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setMargin(float, float)

Comment: @Beasly - actually - the links you posted are better and more informative than mine (which were the official Google developer info). This suggests that there are better resources and worked examples out there than the "official stuff" - nice one !

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to customize Toast:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtToast);
text.setTypeface(typeface_obj);
setText(ArabicClass.Convert(getResources().getString(R.string.ar_netork_failure)));
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 200);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: i had to use toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 200);
 instead of toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Custom Toast in android can be easily done.
First of all. Create your own xml layout with the widgets that you want in your Toast and then inflate the layout.Then use the inflated layout to find the view objects and the set its contents then create the Toast. As the code would be long. I've just explained how I've done it.

I've explained easily about this in my blog: http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/custom-notification-in-android-with-an-example/

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

View view = toast.getView();

TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);

v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);

ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f43f10"));

view.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find here http://android-apps-blog.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-display-custom-toast-in-android.html a good tutorian on How to create a Custom Toast Notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your custom toast than the only best thing is to create custom dialog or you can say custom alert box which you can design same as toast in your app by using themes of dialog box.
To see tutorial for custom box here is a youtube link
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBXMoMB9-k0

Hope this will helpful to you..